# R Check: Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE) : there is no package called 'AttMOMO'

Tags: r, r-package

When running Check of a package I get an error on "checking whether package 'AttMOMO' can be installed"

```
Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE) :
  there is no package called 'AttMOMO'
Installation failed.
   See 'H:/SFSD/INFEPI/Projekter/AKTIVE/MOMO/AttMOMO/AttMOMO.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.


H:/SFSD/INFEPI/Projekter/AKTIVE/MOMO/AttMOMO/AttMOMO.Rcheck/00install.out:
* installing *source* package 'AttMOMO' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE) :
  there is no package called 'AttMOMO'
Error: loading failed
Execution stopped
ERROR: loading failed
* removing 'H:/SFSD/INFEPI/Projekter/AKTIVE/MOMO/AttMOMO/AttMOMO.Rcheck/AttMOMO'
```

I am using R 4.2.3. Hope someone may help me.

Comment: is that a package on CRAN ?

Comment: What instruction have you ran to throw that error, `install.packages("AttMOMO")`?

Comment: No, Mike, it's not a CRAN package

Comment: I have the package on my desktop and did a Build/Check Package